# Using the same Boost.Asio io_service for accepting tcp connections synchronously and as a thread pool

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

Is the following method of using io_service for accepting tcp connections and also as a thread pool for serving connected clients valid, or is there some caveat?

```
io_service svc;
io_service::work work(svc);

// define the three threads in the io_service thread pool
thread t1( [&svc]() { svc.run(); } );
thread t2( [&svc]() { svc.run(); } );
thread t3( [&svc]() { svc.run(); } );

endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v4(), port);
acceptor acceptor(svc, ep);

while (true) {
  shared_ptr<socket> sock(new socket(svc));
  acceptor.accept(*sock);

  // post a task to the io_service
  svc.post( [sock]() {  /* do stuff on sock here */ });
}

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly fine.

A caveat would be if you post tasks that block for non-trivial amounts of time.

Async IO operations all imply *very short* execution times. If you clog the service threads with non-IO tasks, the IO tasks will get high(er) latency

Comment: In the case of the example, I'm guessing that along with the three threads I am creating, the main thread also processes tasks from the io_service queue. Is there a call to run / run_one somewhere inside accept which could also end up servicing the client and therefore introduce latency in serving a new connection?

Comment: There are no calls to run/run_once in the library code (well, except inside `run()` itself, perhaps). Which threads run the serivce, how, is the user's decision